# Inkscape: make path more edgy

Tags: inkscape, path-effects

Inkscape has the simplify tool, which removes some nodes along the path and makes it smooth. Is there something like simplify, but which instead makes the path more edgy? The path is traced bitmap, so doing so by hand is impossible.

For comparison, this is a bitmap traced and post-processed as vector (probably in Photoshop and then Illustrator), which keeps the edges of the color patches and gives it some energy:

[image: edgy]

while this is my attempt (with a different image) to produce similar effect in Inkscape, where, however, every smoothing from the trace leads to rounded corners and theresult feels blunt:

[image: smoother]

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select all nodes within a path and change node type to Corner. That will make the path into a polygon like in your first image.[image: corner node type]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the Fractalize extension might do what you want... or it might be way too strong of an effect! It's on the Extensions menu under Modify Path.